# Alarmist Malthusian fears or alarmist Malthusian fears

Tags: articles

In the following sentence

[The projections should be viewed in perspective, considering that **alarmist Malthusian fears** of inability to provide for more than a billion people on earth did not come true.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/a-stable-planet/article28102991.ece)

I think It should be **the alarmist Malthusian fears of......**

I do not exactly know the reason but as a rule of thumb in such constructions When an adjective is placed before a noun the definite article **the** is used

Comment: The article is *optional* in your context. Including it implies greater acknowledgement / recognition of "Malthusian fears", so given the writer is clearly *dismissive* of any such fears, he has good reason for not including the article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers   would say it is not optional, but rather changes the meaning. Piyush Yadav, why do you think it is required? Where did you learn this as a "rule"?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

> The projections should be viewed in perspective, considering that **alarmist Malthusian fears** of inability to provide for more than a billion people on earth did not come true.

is grammatical and idiomatic. One could also say "**the** alarmist Malthusian fears" but that would subtly change the meaning. That would mean that there was one set of such fears, widely known and considered to be a thing. However, if there were several or many varieties of such fears, with perhaps different emphasizes or theoretical bases, the definite article would be wrong.

There is no general rule that a noun phrase consisting of {adjective}+{noun} or {adjective}+{adjective}+{noun} (as in the example) must be preceded by a definite article. Some examples:

> - Tasty fish (there may be many)
> - the tasty fish (a specific fish or group of fish is being refereed to, context msut indicate which)
> - the conservative Christian mainstream (there is presumably only one such mainstream )
> - conservative Christian politicians (three may be many different ones)
> - the Marxist economic theory (the speaker is saying that ther is only one such theory , or is treating it as a single thing)
> - Marxist economic theory (there may be several shades or varieties of such theory)

Comment: I think you're being overanalytical here. Given that (particularised or not) "Malthusian fears" are being summarily dismissed (because history has proved them wrong) in OP's context, I can't see that any normal reader would infer any implications about whether there might have been *identifiably distinct kinds* of such fears, based on the presence or absence of an article. What including it *does* tend to imply is that they once had significant "status", and would still be familiar to most readers, even though now discredited. So *not* including it amplifies the writer's dismissive attitude.